# Minimum and maximum values for Perl hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash, max, min

This is a variation from another question asked on perlmonks and is similar to the problem I'm trying to figure out. I have the following hash of hashes.

```
%Year = (
  2007 => {
    ID1  => 07,
    ID4  => 34,
    ID2  => 24,
    ID9  => 14,
    ID3  => 05,
  },
  2008 => {
    ID7  => 11,
    ID9  => 64,
    ID10 => 20,
    ID5  => 13,
    ID8  => 22,
  }           
)
```

I would like to find the *two* smallest and *two* largest values together with their corresponding IDs for each year. Can this be done using [`List::Util qw (min max)`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Util)?

Desired results:

```
2007 - max1:ID4,34 max2:ID2,24 min1:ID3,05 min2:ID1,07
2008 - max1:ID9,64 max2:ID10,20 min1:ID7,11 min2:ID5,13
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it with the `List::Util` module?

Comment: I would give [`List::MoreUtils qw(minmax);`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils) a look.

Comment: @Borodin - I've used it to find min max values but could not figure out how to do this with the corresponding key. Also how to use it to find the next best min and max.

Comment: This question is not specific to List::Util. I was merely asking if it was possible with that module. Any suggested solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TIMTOWDI:** You've mentioned hash of hash, so you can sort your inner hash by values and take a slice (that is first two and last two elements).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %Year = (
    2007 => { ID1  =>  7, ID2 => 24, ID3 =>  5, ID4 => 34, ID9 => 14 },
    2008 => { ID10 => 20, ID5 => 13, ID7 => 11, ID8 => 22, ID9 => 64 },
);

for my $year (keys %Year) {
    printf "%4d - max1:%s,%02d max2:%s,%02d min1:%s,%02d min2:%s,%02d\n", 
    $year, 
    map { $_, $Year{$year}{$_} } 
    ( sort { $Year{$year}{$b} <=> $Year{$year}{$a} } keys %{$Year{$year}} )[0,1,-1,-2];
}
```

**Output:**

```
2007 - max1:ID4,34 max2:ID2,24 min1:ID3,05 min2:ID1,07
2008 - max1:ID9,64 max2:ID8,22 min1:ID7,11 min2:ID5,13
```

Comment: This works great. How can I map them in another hash instead of printing to std out? So that I can have it in memory for further manipulation.

Comment: @user2674514 How do you want to store it in hash? Just like how the original hash is laid out?

Comment: %storehash = (
       ID4 => {'value' => 34, 'type' => max1, 'year' => 2007},
       ID2 => {'value' => 24, 'type' => max2, 'year' => 2007},
       ID3 => {'value' => 05, 'type' => min1, 'year' => 2007},
       ID1 => {'value' => 07, 'type' => min2, 'year' => 2007}, 
       ID9 => {'value' => 64, 'type' => max1, 'year' => 2008},  
     ID8 => {'value' => 22, 'type' => max2, 'year' => 2008},
     ID7 => {'value' => 11, 'type' => min1, 'year' => 2008},
     ID5 => {'value' => 13, 'type' => min2, 'year' => 2008},
    )

Comment: @user2674514: You can't have a hash like that as the same ID can appear in more than one year's data

Answer (score 2):

Unless the lists are huge, it is probably best to find the *two* largest and *two* smallest hash values just by sorting the entire hash and picking the first two and last two elements.

You seem to have incorrect expectations for your output. For 2008 the hash data sorted by value looks like

```
ID7  => 11
ID5  => 13
ID10 => 20
ID8  => 22
ID9  => 64
```

so `max1` and `max2` are `ID9` and `ID8`, while `min1` and `min2` are are `ID7` and `ID5`. But your question says that you expect `max2` to be `ID10`, whose value is 20 - right in the middle of the sorted range. I think `max2` should be `ID8` which has a value of 22 - the second largest value in the 2008 hash.

I suggest this solution to produce the output that I think you want

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %year = (
  2007 => { ID1  =>  7, ID2 => 24, ID3 =>  5, ID4 => 34, ID9 => 14 },
  2008 => { ID10 => 20, ID5 => 13, ID7 => 11, ID8 => 22, ID9 => 64 },
);

for my $year (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %year) {

  my $data = $year{$year};
  my @sorted_keys = sort { $data->{$a} <=> $data->{$b} } keys %$data;

  printf "%4d - max1:%s,%02d max2:%s,%02d min1:%s,%02d min2:%s,%02d\n",
      $year, map { $_ => $data->{$_} } @sorted_keys[-1,-2,0,1];
}
```

**output**

```
2007 - max1:ID4,34 max2:ID2,24 min1:ID3,05 min2:ID1,07
2008 - max1:ID9,64 max2:ID8,22 min1:ID7,11 min2:ID5,13
```

Comment: Year is the name of the hash, not %data.

Comment: @user2674514: Ah, you show a hash reference in your question so I assumed that Year was an element of another hash. Okay I've fixed your question and my answer.

Comment: @user2674514: Ah, you show a hash reference in your question and use `Year` instead of `%Year`. You also use `=` throughout instead of `=>` so I assumed that `Year` was an element of another hash. Okay I've fixed your question and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have hashes, and [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) works on lists/arrays. That disqualifies you right there since both the keys and the data are still important for you.

It's possible to create a second hash that's keyed by the data, then I could use something from `List::Util` or `List::MoreUtils` on that to pull up the data you want, and then look up the keys for that data. However, that's a lot of work just to get the information you want.

In reality, you're not sorting the hash of hashes, but just the data in each year. This makes the job a lot easier.

Normally, when you sort a hash, you're sorting on the keys. However, you can specify a subroutine inside the sort command to change the way Perl sorts. Perl will hand you two items `$a` and `$b` which represents the keys to your hash. You figure out which is the bigger one, and pass that back to Perl. Perl gives you `<=>` for numbers and `cmp` for non-numeric data.

All I have to do is specify `sort { $array{$a} cmp $array{$b} } keys %array` to sort by the data and not the keys. I simply toss the sorted keys into another array, then use index positioning to pull out the data I want.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

my %year;

#
# Data
#
$year{2007}->{ID1} = "07";
$year{2007}->{ID2} = "24";
$year{2007}->{ID3} = "05";
$year{2007}->{ID4} = "34";
$year{2007}->{ID9} = "14";

$year{2008}->{ID7} = "11";
$year{2008}->{ID9} = "64";
$year{2008}->{ID10} = "20";
$year{2008}->{ID5} = "13";
$year{2008}->{ID8} = "22";

#
# For Each Year...
#
for my $year ( sort keys %year ) {
    print "$year - ";
    #
    # No need to do this dereferencing, but it makes the rest of the code cleaner
    #
    my %id_hash = %{ $year{$year} };
    #
    # Now I sort my IDs by their data and not the key names
    #
    my @keys = sort { $id_hash{$a} cmp $id_hash{$b} } keys %id_hash;
    #
    # And print them out
    #
    print "max1:$keys[-1],$id_hash{$keys[-1]} ";
    print "max2:$keys[-2],$id_hash{$keys[-2]} ";
    print "min1:$keys[0],$id_hash{$keys[0]}, ";
    print "min2:$keys[1],$id_hash{$keys[1]}\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
2007 - max1:ID4,34 max2:ID2,24 min1:ID3,05, min2:ID1,07
2008 - max1:ID9,64 max2:ID8,22 min1:ID7,11, min2:ID5,13
```

Comment: There is no need to copy each year's hash. Use `my $id_hash = $year{$year}` to copy the *reference*, and use `$id_hash->{$key}` wherever you had `$id_hash{$key}` before

Comment: @David - I don't seem to get the correct max and mins with this.

Comment: @user2674514 Programmatically, all the answers are similar. The key here is the sort line where you're sorting by the contents of the hash rather than the hash. Jaypal's answer collapses everything into a single statement. I spell it out. However, one key difference is that I sort by string using `cmp` and others sort numerically using `<=>`. I did this because you have one data item that's zero filled. To me, that meant the data might be string data. Change `cmp` to `<=>` in my program, and it will work the same as the others.

Comment: @David - Thank you for the clarification. Yes, changing to <=> provides the correct results.